# Datatype of escape sequences in c++

Tags: c++

I am still a beginner.

Some of my teachers say that escape sequences are characters while others say they are "special" strings.

What are they exactly?

Comment: Strings are sequences of characters. The two answers don't contradict each other.

Comment: Both descriptions are reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape sequences are a set of characters. So the datatype simply depends on the way you use them.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you enclose the escape sequence, single quote or double quote.

Basically, an escape sequence resembles a single character represented differently in code from what it actually looks like.

```
char ch = '\n'; // This is a character
const char *s = "\n"; // This is a string.
```

In the above examples in C, `\n` represents a newline when inside a string literal or character literal. There will be no more backslashes and Ns when the code is compiled into binary - the compiler has converted the escape sequence to what it resembles.

Sum up:

```
\n    // an escape sequence (don't use directly)
'\n'  // a character containing an esc seq
"\n"  // a string containint an esc seq
```

My understanding:

An escape sequence is a sequence (more than 1) of characters written in code, that does not mean what it literally is, but another character. It will be converted to that character after compiling.

Answer (score 1):

Escape sequences are used to represent certain special characters within string literals and character literals.

From [wikipedia](http://Escape%20sequences%20in%20C):

> Escape sequences are used in the programming languages C and C++, and
>   also in many more languages (with some variations) like Java and C#.
>   **An escape sequence is a sequence of characters** that does not represent itself when used inside a character or string literal, but
>   is translated into another character or a sequence of characters that
>   may be difficult or impossible to represent directly.
>
> In C, all **escape sequences consist of two or more characters, the
>   first of which is the backslash, \ (called the "Escape character");
>   the remaining characters determine the interpretation of the escape
>   sequence.** For example, `\n` is an escape sequence that denotes a newline
>   character. The remainder of this article focuses on C; other
>   programming languages are likely to have different syntax and
>   semantics.

From [string_literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

**Syntax**

> ```
> " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "  (1) 
>
> L " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "    (2) 
>
> u8 " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "   (3) (since C++11)
>
> u " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "    (4) (since C++11)
>
> U " (unescaped_character|escaped_character)* "    (5) (since C++11)
>
> prefix(optional) R "delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter" (6) (since C++11)
> ```

From [character_literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal):

**Syntax**

> ' c-char '    (1)
>
> u8 ' c-char ' (2) (since C++17)
>
> u ' c-char '  (3) (since C++11)
>
> U ' c-char '  (4) (since C++11)
>
> L ' c-char '  (5)
>
> ' c-char-sequence '   (6)
>
> **where**
>
> - c-char is either
>
>   1. a character from the basic source character set minus single-quote ('), backslash (), or the newline character,
>   2. escape sequence, as defined in escape sequences
>   3. universal character name, as defined in escape sequences
> - c-char-sequence is a sequence of two or more c-chars.
>
>   1. narrow character literal or ordinary character literal, e.g. `'a'` or
>        `'\n'` or `'\13'`. Such literal has type char and the value equal to the
>        representation of c-char in the execution character set. If c-char is
>        not representable as a single byte in the execution character set, the
>        literal has type int and implementation-defined value

Comment: does this mean that calling escape sequences as either characters or Strings generally will be wrong

Comment: @JavaRookie No. It's contect-dependent.

Comment: do you mean it depends on situations i mean the way the sequences are used?

Comment: @JavaRookie See my answer. Both `'\n'` and `"\n"` **contains** escape sequences. They are not escape sequences. The formar is a character while the latter is a string.

Answer (score 1):

An escape sequence is an alternative way to encode a character in the source code a character. Their most important role is to represent characters that cannot be used directly in the code.

There are two categories of such characters:

- unprintable characters (ASCII codes 0..31), characters whose appearance used to depend on a code page (ASCII codes 128..255) and multi-byte characters;
- characters that have a special meaning for the language and that meaning is related to the representation of strings inside the language.

The characters from the first category (except for the [`NUL` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character)) can be represented by themselves in a C string but they might look strange or different on different computers; they are just an annoyance.

The most known characters from this group are the newline (`\n`), the tab character (`\t`) and the [`NUL` character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character) (`\0`).

The characters from the second category cannot be used because they have a special meaning. These characters are the quotes (`"`) (its presence means the end of the string) and the apostrophe (`'`) (used to enclose a character literal).

In order to have one of them into the language representation of a character or string they have to be escaped. This means, inside a string, `\"` represents the `"` character and the apostrophe character is encoded as `'\''`.

This way, the backslash character (`\`) also becomes special and it must be escaped (`\\`) to represent itself in a string or as a character.